# How can I set the Title for a UINavigation Bar programmatically?

Tags: iphone

How can I set the Title for a UINavigation Bar programmatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
self.title = @"My View";
```

or

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My View";
```

Depending on if you are using a `UINavigationController` or not.

Comment: Since I was not using a UINavigationController I used the second syntax after creating an IBOutlet to navigationBar. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The title that is shown in UINavigationBar comes from the currently active UIViewController.

For example, let's say we want a UINavigationController with a root view controller called MyCustomViewController.

In our app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIViewController *myCustomViewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCustomViewController];
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

In MyCustomViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Hello World!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view controller implementation file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
             self.title = @"My Title";
     }
     return self;
}
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully set the title on viewcontroller push. Or rather, before the push. Here is my code for this..

```
    _chatTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatTableViewController"];
    _chatTableViewController.title = @"Live Chat";
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:_chatTableViewController animated:YES];
```